# Highlight daterange in jQuery UI datepicker on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm having some trouble with my jQuery UI Datepicker.
I've managed to make it highlight my daterange when I select a start and end date (e.g. 2015/12/02 - 2015/12/08) - then the dates between is highlighted in a green color.

My question is now - can I highligt a daterange BEFORE I select an end date?

Here's an example: 
http://stephencelis.github.io/timeframe/#example_information

When I select a startdate, it highlights the daterange until I select my desired end-date. I'm not sure if it's something that can be done in jQuery UI Datepicker - and if not, then I have to find something else - but it's worth a try asking in here :)

Here is my code so far:

```
$(function() {

var disabledDate = ["13-12-2015", "14-12-2015", "15-12-2015"];

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["da"]);

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        /* numberOfMonths: [4,2], */
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        firstDay: 1,
        inline: true,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
            if(disabledDate.indexOf(string) == -1) {

            } else {
                return[false, 'disabled-dates'];
            };

            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateFrom").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateTo").val());
            return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "selected-dates" : ""];

        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateFrom").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateTo").val());

            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

            if (!date1 || date2) {

                $("#chooseDateFrom").val(dateText);
                $("#chooseDateTo").val("");

                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);

            } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {

                $("#chooseDateTo").val( $("#chooseDateFrom").val() );
                $("#chooseDateFrom").val( dateText );

                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);

            } else {

                $("#chooseDateTo").val(dateText);

                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);

            }
        }
});
});
```

I hope someone can help me a bit :) I'm kinda stuck here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help you....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var disabledDate = ["13-12-2015", "14-12-2015", "15-12-2015"];

     $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        /* numberOfMonths: [4,2], */
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        firstDay: 1,
        inline: true,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
            if(disabledDate.indexOf(string) == -1) {

            } else {
                return[false, 'disabled-dates'];
            };

            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateFrom").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateTo").val());
            return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "selected-dates" : ""];

        },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateFrom").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#chooseDateTo").val());

            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

            if (!date1 || date2) {

                $("#chooseDateFrom").val(dateText);
                $("#chooseDateTo").val("");

                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);

            } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {

                $("#chooseDateTo").val( $("#chooseDateFrom").val() );
                $("#chooseDateFrom").val( dateText );

                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);

            } else {

                $("#chooseDateTo").val(dateText);

                $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);                   

            }
             setTimeout("$('a.ui-state-default').attr('onmouseover','setBackColor(this)');",1000); 
        }
});

$('a.ui-state-default').attr('onmouseover','setBackColor(this)');    

 });
  function setBackColor(object){
    var day1=parseInt($(object).html());
    var month1=parseInt($(object).parents("td").attr("data-month"));
    var year1=parseInt($(object).parents("td").attr("data-year"));
    var date1=new Date(year1,month1, day1);
 //$("#chooseDateFrom").val(date1);
    if(Date.parse(document.getElementById('chooseDateFrom').value)){
    $("a.ui-state-default").each(function(){            
        var obj = this;
        var day=parseInt($(obj).html());
        var month=parseInt($(obj).parents("td").attr("data-month"));
        var year=parseInt($(obj).parents("td").attr("data-year"));
        var date=new Date(year,month, day);
        if(new Date($("#chooseDateFrom").val())<=date && date<=date1){
            $(obj).css("background-color","#78F764");
        }else{
            $(obj).css("background-color",'#e6e6e6');
        }
    });
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Atikur, I wondered where your comments went - but now I understamd :) I get following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: setBackColor is not defined" - Please see Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kucko/8zrrc3wu/

Comment: please dont test in fiddle. but direct implement it. i was also wondered that this works on our server perfect but not work in fiddle. please try it.

Comment: Hi Atikur, it's not working on my website aswell. Please have a look http://bit.ly/1U1Ad4u .. Nothing in the console aswell.

Comment: Hi Atikur - Finally! I made it work! The error was on my side :) Thanks a BUNCH! You saved me a lot of work :)